# Change color of popover in lighting:helptext

Tags: lightning

I'd like to change font color and background of popover of `lighting:helptext`.
I'm talking about this component:

```
<lightning:helptext content="Your Name will be your login name" />
```

I tried to apply slds class directly as the value of `class` attribute, but it only changes the icon. Is it possible to change the font color and background of popover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change font color and background of `lighting:helptext` popover by overriding CSS style within yourComponent.css file.

For instance, in this case, we will get a popover with a red background and a gray text:

```
.THIS .slds-popover_tooltip, 
.THIS .slds-popover--tooltip {
    background: #FF0000; /* background color */
    color: #444444; /* text color */
}
```

But be careful as this approach will apply this style to all popovers on the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it doesn't work. Nothing changes. Should I define a class or id in lightning:helptext? I tried with differents class name and slds name (In class). but nothing works.

Comment: you should only override default style in your css file. I recommend you to read about LC bundle structure.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_bundle.htm

Comment: and about CSS in Components https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm

Comment: Have you solved this? I don't know why it is challenging to just change a color in SF

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot change any CSS for SLDS popovers**, I went through and found that the HTML for popover (lightning-primitive-bubble) is being created outside the context of enclosing Aura Application and is direct Child of body tag in the rendered HTML.

Since .THIS will be replaced by the Application/Component's class name, it means it can only modify CSS within it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have another solution for changing the color?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by creating a css file with the following content:

.slds-popover_tooltip, .slds-popover--tooltip {
background: #477626 !important
}

Next, load the static resource in my component con ltng:require and it worked correctly for me both in Salesforce and in a Lightning Community.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I've just added `aura:html tag="style"` in cmp file.

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-popover_tooltip, .slds-popover--tooltip {
        background: #3D6E74;
    }
</aura:html>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Oleh Berehovskyi

It´s works. but in following way.

```
.slds-popover_tooltip, 
.slds-popover--tooltip {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

without `.THIS`, and font color not change. 
Thank you very much.